# string variable in where clause with dynamic pl/sql

Tags: sql, plsql, execute-immediate

I have this code:

```
declare
  instr varchar2(20);
  num_no number;

begin 
    select AR_ID, ID
    into instr, num_no
    from quelle_match
    where ID = 1;

      execute immediate 'CREATE or replace VIEW interm2 AS
      SELECT AR_ID, kurs,
        ((TO_CHAR(to_date(di.kursdatum,''dd.mm.yyyy''),''YYYYMMDD''))+    (TO_CHAR(to_date(di.verfall,''dd.mm.yyyy''),''YYYYMMDD''))) AS dumdate
      FROM daten_import di 
      where di.AR_ID = '||instr||'';      

  -- where di.AR_ID = ''GXIndex''';

end ;
```

I get error b/c instr is not valid. When I substitute the variable with the actual string GXIndex, the code works. It also works with numbers as the variable, but not with string. Why is that?

Comment: Have you tried with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE USING ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816402/using-bind-variables-with-dynamic-select-into-clause-in-pl-sql

Comment: See also this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634601/ora-00907-when-dynamically-creating-a-view-in-pl-sql-and-using-a-clob

Comment: Very likely your `instr`-variable is not correctly quoted when you construct string for `execute immediate`.

Comment: Use a print statement to print out the value if `instr` before `execute immediate`. I think @user272735 is probably on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
  execute immediate 'CREATE or replace VIEW interm2 AS
  SELECT AR_ID, kurs,
    ((TO_CHAR(to_date(di.kursdatum,''dd.mm.yyyy''),''YYYYMMDD''))+    (TO_CHAR(to_date(di.verfall,''dd.mm.yyyy''),''YYYYMMDD''))) AS dumdate
  FROM daten_import di 
  where di.AR_ID = '||instr||'';
```

should be:

```
  execute immediate 'CREATE or replace VIEW interm2 AS
  SELECT AR_ID, kurs,
    ((TO_CHAR(to_date(di.kursdatum,''dd.mm.yyyy''),''YYYYMMDD''))+    (TO_CHAR(to_date(di.verfall,''dd.mm.yyyy''),''YYYYMMDD''))) AS dumdate
  FROM daten_import di 
  where di.AR_ID = '||instr;
```

if `instr` is an integer, which I think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the way you concatenate `instr`. For clarity, let me simplify your problem:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW interm2 AS
   SELECT ar_id FROM daten_import di
   WHERE di.ar_id = ' || instr;
```

`instr` is a string. You need to have quotes around it.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW interm2 AS
   SELECT ar_id FROM daten_import di
   WHERE di.ar_id = ''' || instr || '''';
--                  ^^               ^^
--                  ||               ||
--                  -- escaped quotes--
```